# How do I get the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice identifier for the Siri I use on my iPhone? Or how can I get one to pronounce words correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

All the voices are useless to me because they can't pronounce words properly.

Tried all sorts of voices and combinations for no luck:

```
var Voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: "com.apple.ttsbundle.Karen_female_en-AUS_compact")
```

There doesn't seem to be a voice that can pronounce words properly. For example: `guacamolé`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, I am guessing that you are looking for the right pronunciation. I don't know what language `gucamolé` is but perhaps using the right language could pronounce it properly?

Try checking this
https://daddycoding.com/2019/06/06/ios-tutorials-make-your-phone-read-with-avspeechsynthesizer/

Currently only these languages are supported

```
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) - ar-SA
Chinese (China) - zh-CN
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) - zh-HK
Chinese (Taiwan) - zh-TW
Czech (Czech Republic) - cs-CZ
Danish (Denmark) - da-DK
Dutch (Belgium) - nl-BE
Dutch (Netherlands) - nl-NL
English (Australia) - en-AU
English (Ireland) - en-IE
English (South Africa) - en-ZA
English (United Kingdom) - en-GB
English (United States) - en-US
Finnish (Finland) - fi-FI
French (Canada) - fr-CA
French (France) - fr-FR
German (Germany) - de-DE
Greek (Greece) - el-GR
Hindi (India) - hi-IN
Hungarian (Hungary) - hu-HU
Indonesian (Indonesia) - id-ID
Italian (Italy) - it-IT
Japanese (Japan) - ja-JP
Korean (South Korea) - ko-KR
Norwegian (Norway) - no-NO
Polish (Poland) - pl-PL
Portuguese (Brazil) - pt-BR
Portuguese (Portugal) - pt-PT
Romanian (Romania) - ro-RO
Russian (Russia) - ru-RU
Slovak (Slovakia) - sk-SK
Spanish (Mexico) - es-MX
Spanish (Spain) - es-ES
Swedish (Sweden) - sv-SE
Thai (Thailand) - th-TH
Turkish (Turkey) - tr-TR
```